# Google Spidering ajax Call URL as Stand Alone Content

Tags: php, ajax, google-search-console, googlebot

My page has an ajax call that loads fresh html content via a separate url.

Google has now spidered these ajax urls and runs it's search console algorythm over them as if it were a stand alone page.

In the live environment, the html returned from the ajax script picks up styles and viewport declarations from the motherpage and renders as expected.

When Googlebot takes a look and spiders the url as a stand alone page, the resulting html fails on mobile userbility (because the styles and viewport info is not available)

Should I prevent Googlebot from spidering the ajax urls using the robots file or is there a better solution to minimising Search Console errors ?

Hunting around for a solution / answer to this question has come up with nothing directly. The closest possible option is for the ajax rendered html to be sent via JSON - but I might have  misunderstood the purpose of using JSON ?

Comment: Questions about influencing the behaviour of Googlebot are better asked on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Quentin - What is the protocol for moving the question into that category please ?